# how to get row number for valid records from file using external table concept

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a CSV file which needs to be loaded into a table .While inserting the data into the table using "external table"concept , for the records rejected from CSV file we can get the row no. and field name from LOG file but for the accepted rows i.e. for rows which got inserted into the table how can we get the row number (which row from CSV file got inserted into the table );

```
CREATE TABLE emp_external
(
EMPNO NUMBER(4),
ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
JOB VARCHAR2(9),
MGR NUMBER(4),
SAL NUMBER(7,2),
COMM NUMBER(7,2),
DEPTNO NUMBER(2)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY my_data
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 LOGFILE my_data:'data.log'
 BADFILE my_data:'data.bad'
 DISCARDFILE my_data:'data.disc'
 fields terminated by ','
 MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
)
 LOCATION (my_data:'emp.csv')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just put one extra field (say Line_Number) at last (after DEPTNO) and fill that field as RECNUM in access parameters portion
Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE emp_external
(
....
....
DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
Line_Number VARCHAR2(10)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
 DEFAULT DIRECTORY my_data
ACCESS PARAMETERS
(RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 LOGFILE my_data:'data.log'
 BADFILE my_data:'data.bad'
 DISCARDFILE my_data:'data.disc'
 fields terminated by ','
 MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
 (
 ....
 ....
 Line_Number RECNUM 
 )
)
 LOCATION (my_data:'emp.csv')
);
```